# ListView Doesn't display anymore than 8 ImageViews

Tags: java, android, listview, imageview

I am decoding jpeg images from a server request I get using json. I display them with a custom ListView Adapter along with a little text.

The images display correctly for the first 8 ImageViews in the ListView, however, after that it will no longer display the image (it will display the text). For example, if I have a total of 10 images, the last two images will not show in the ListView, but if I delete the first 2 images, the last two will show, so there is no concern about retrieving the actual images.

On my main activity (NotesActivity) I have a button that goes to another activity which does an asyntask, and in that async task in the onPostExecute, it returns back to the main activity where it should show the updated list (and it does, unless there are more than 8 images).

I don't know where to begin, any suggestions?

My Activity that contains the ListView

```
public class NotesActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    String key = "NOTES";
    String key2 = "UPDATE_NOTES";

    Gson gson = new Gson();
    // Notes myNotes = new Notes();
    NotesList myNotes = new NotesList();
    String bId;
    String res = null;
    EditText notes;
    Button save;
    private Button createNote;
    private int position;
    private String type;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.notes_layout);
        createNote = (Button) findViewById(R.id.notes_layout_btn_createNote);
        Bundle bundle = this.getIntent().getExtras();
        position = bundle.getInt("position");
        type = bundle.getString("type");

        //
        if (type.equals("LISTINGS")) {
            Listings it = ListingsFragment.myListings.getListings().get(
                    position);
            bId = it.getBID();
            notes = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.notes);
        }
        //
        if (type.equals("SHARED")) {
            Listings it = SharedFragment.myShared.getListings().get(position);
            bId = it.getBID();
            notes = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.notes);
        }
        GetNotes getNotes = new GetNotes();
        try {
            NotesList copy = new NotesList();

            getNotes.execute(key, bId).get();
            for (int j = 0; j < myNotes.getNotes().size(); j++) {
                Notes note = myNotes.getNotes().get(j);
                System.out.println("Removed value: " + note.getIsRemoved());
                if (note.getIsRemoved() == null) {
                    copy.getNotes().add(note);
                }
            }
            NotesAdapter adapter = new NotesAdapter(this, R.layout.note_row,
                    copy.getNotes());
            ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.notes_layout_lv_notesList);
            lv.setAdapter(adapter);
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
        createNote.setOnClickListener(this);

    }

    private class GetNotes extends AsyncTask<String, String, NotesList> {

        @Override
        protected NotesList doInBackground(String... things) {

            ArrayList<NameValuePair> postParameters = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("key", things[0]));
            postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("bId", things[1]));

            // String valid = "1";
            String response = null;

            try {
                response = CustomHttpClient.executeHttpPost(
                        "http://propclip.dev/mobile.php", postParameters);
                res = response.toString();
                // System.out.println("This is the response " + res);
                // res = res.trim();
                // res= res.replaceAll("\\s+","");
                // error.setText(res);
                // System.out.println(res);
                myNotes = gson.fromJson(res, NotesList.class);
                // System.out.println(res);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                res = e.toString();
            }
            return myNotes;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(NotesList res) {
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.notes_layout_btn_createNote:
            ProfileDataSource datasource = new ProfileDataSource(this);
            datasource.open();
            PropClipGlobal pcg = datasource.getUserIdenity();
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, NewNoteActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("bId", bId);
            intent.putExtra("uId", pcg.getUID());
            intent.putExtra("username", pcg.getEm());
            intent.putExtra("position", position);
            intent.putExtra("type", type);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }
}
```

My custom adapter

```
public class NotesAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Notes> {
    List<Notes> notes;
    Context context;

    public NotesAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<Notes> notes) {
        super(context, resource, notes);
        this.notes = notes;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View v = convertView;
        if (v == null) {
            LayoutInflater vi;
            vi = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
            v = vi.inflate(R.layout.note_row, null);
        }

        Notes note = notes.get(position);
        ImageView icon = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.note_row_icon);
        TextView name = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.note_row_name);
        TextView message = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.note_row_message);
        TextView date = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.note_row_date);
        String input = note.getNoteDate();
        SimpleDateFormat inputDf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
        SimpleDateFormat outputDf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd, yyyy");
        SimpleDateFormat monthFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM");
        Date myDate = null;
        try {
            myDate = inputDf.parse(input);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        String month = monthFormat.format(myDate);
        date.setText(getMonth(Integer.parseInt(month)) + " "
                + outputDf.format(myDate));
        message.setText(note.getNote());
        name.setText(note.getFirstName() + " " + note.getLastName());
        // System.out.println(p.getFileData());
        byte[] imageAsBytes = Base64.decode(note.getFileData().getBytes(),
                position);
        icon.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imageAsBytes, 0,
                imageAsBytes.length));
        System.out.println(note.getFileData());
        return v;
    }

    public String getMonth(int month) {
        return new DateFormatSymbols().getMonths()[month - 1];
    }
}
```

Activity which eventually goes to the main activity (NotesActivity)

```
public class NewNoteActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
    private String uId;
    private String bId;
    private String username;
    private String response;
    private String key = "UPDATE_NOTES";
    private Button submit;
    private EditText note;
    private int position;
    private String type;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_new_note);
        submit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.activity_new_note_btn_submit);
        note = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.activity_new_note_et_note);
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        bId = intent.getStringExtra("bId");
        uId = intent.getStringExtra("uId");
        username = intent.getStringExtra("username");
        position = intent.getIntExtra("position", 0);
        type = intent.getStringExtra("type");
        submit.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.new_note, menu);
        return true;
    }

    private class UpdateNotes extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... values) {

            ArrayList<NameValuePair> postParameters = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("key", values[0]));
            postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("bId", values[1]));
            postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("uId", values[2]));
            postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", values[3]));
            postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("note", values[4]));

            String response = null;

            try {
                response = CustomHttpClient.executeHttpPost(
                        "http://propclip.dev/mobile.php", postParameters);
                response = response.toString();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                response = e.toString();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String response) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                    NotesActivity.class);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            intent.putExtra("position", position);
            intent.putExtra("type", type);
            startActivity(intent);
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Added note!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
            toast.show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        String noteMessage = note.getText().toString();
        UpdateNotes updateNotes = new UpdateNotes();
        updateNotes.execute(key, bId, uId, username, noteMessage);
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that 'BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imageAsBytes, 0,    imageAsBytes.length)' != null?

Comment: Hmm strange, yes some are null. Do you know what might be affecting this? I print out the string and it seems it's exactly the same as every other one...

Comment: Could it be running out of memory? I read a comment last week (no idea why) that storing bitmaps seems to take lots of memory and they are not garbage collected very well. I make sure I call recycle on them as soon as I am done with them.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/manage-memory.html